# mysql retrieve user information from group chat table

Tags: mysql

i have  3 table

`discussion_chat` with (`discussion_Chat_id,discussion_id,user_id,content,created_date,updated_date`)

[image]

`end_user`

[image],

`psychology`

[image: psychology tabe]

i want to select with `discussion_id`=some value

and if the `user_id` is in `end_user` get user name else if it is in `psycology` get name

i can only get from end_user only

```
SELECT
    discussion_chat.user_id,
    discussion_chat.created_date,
    discussion_chat.content,
    end_user.first_name
FROM
    `discussion_chat` discussion_chat
INNER JOIN `end_user` AS end_user
ON
    discussion_chat.discussion_id = 53 AND discussion_chat.user_id = end_user.end_user_id
```

[image]

i want to get the user name if the use_id is in psycology

Comment: Write two queries, one that joins with `end_user`, the other joins with `psychology`. Then combine them with `UNION`.

Comment: Please share your simple data/expected output as text not images https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors#:~:text=Instead%20of%20using%20images%2C%20paste,%2C%20or%20use%20code%20fences.)